# Using the slice filter with context data from a Django QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to split a list from my model across two columns, using this html code in the template:

```
< div class ="col-md-6" >
{%for value in object_list %}
<ul>< ahref="/sites/{{value.url}}/">{{value.Site}}</a></ul>
{% endfor %}
```

I was planning to achieve this with the slice tag to filter the list, e.g.:

```
{%for value in object_list|slice:"10:20" %}
```

It does not work however, and I think it might be because I have context data i.e. {{value.Site}}, instead of just {{Site}} for example. This is the corresponding view:

```
class homeview(ListView):
    template_name = 'annual_means/home.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return AnnualMean.objects.values("Site", "url").distinct()
```

What do I need to do to get the slice to work?

Comment: You haven't said what "does not work" means.

Comment: The slice filter makes no difference if I include it or leave it out. Sorry I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think, what you need is this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>URL</th>
    <th>SITE</th>
  </tr>
  {% for value in object_list %}
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/sites/{{value.url}}/">{{value.url}}</a></td>
    <td>{{value.Site}}</td>
  </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</table>
```

URLs and Sites will be displayed as a table.

Comment: I tried this and it gave a table, not exactly what I was looking for, but I think it will still be very useful.

Comment: @Paulos  I don't understand what are you trying to achieve here. Please tell us the desired result and With an example.